# Java unknown number of class instances

Tags: java, class, instance

I am building a game where there is a ship that fires missiles(there is a *Player* class for the ship and a *Missile* class for the missiles), but I don´t know exactly how many missiles will be shot throughout the whole game. That means I cannot just `Missile one = new Missile(...)`, if so I would have to declare a billion of missiles. My question: Is there a simple way, in Java, of creating a dynamic number of object instances which are not stored in variables for each?

Comment: You don't want "nameless" classes, but you can store an arbitrary number of instances in the java.util Collections classes (Set, Map, List, etc... depending on your specific needs).   One datastructure class instance holds them all.

Comment: Do you know about arrays? Or collections (`List`s etc)? (Also, do you know the difference between objects and variables?)

Comment: @immibis - OP said he doesn't know how many objects there will be, arrays are not helpful.

Comment: @BadZen they may be a useful intermediate step. Also, it *is* possible to store an unknown number of objects using an array - all it means is the array size is also not known in advance.

Comment: You dont mean "nameless classes" but more likely "dynamic number of object instances which are not stored in variables for each".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also worth noting that while I know little about your game I somehow imagine individual missiles might be quite short lived objects and you might just want to discard them throughout the game.

The ever present garbage collector will deal with all your spent ordnance.

Comment: I know how to "delete" my objects from the game. Your answer does not answer my question.

Comment: @gabzerbinato:  It was meant to. In the oldest such game ever (Space Invaders) the player can fire as many missiles as they liked but there is only one missile at a time. That's not just to make the game harder but also simplifies the code considerably. If you don't know how many missiles will be 'in play' at a given time you need some kind of collection. My point is that there are simpler ways to solve not knowing how many missiles will be fired.

Comment: You are right, thank you for showing me another possibility for my game.

Answer (score 1):

You just create the Missle objects whenever one is fired. It depends on what you need to do with them to track them. It might be enough to add them to a GUI container and they can manage themself. Or if you want to have them all accessable, then you add them to a List or Map (or Array if you can limit the number).

```
List<Missle> missles = new ArrayList<Missle>();
missles.add(new Missle());
...
missles.add(new Missle());
System.out.println("You have currently " + missles.length() + " missles.");
```